# Получение элемента под другим элементом

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Сразу ссылку на пример http://jsfiddle.net/z4onhggp/

В каждой td храниться какое-то значение, проблема в том, что из-за навигации (линии x и y) я не могу получить это значение, событие hover не срабатывает ибо навигация всегда под курсором

Answer (score 1):

Не работает совсем, потому что у вас переменная написана неправильно, вместо `cell_inf` написано `cell_hz`, если переименовать то работать начинает, но всё равно не так как надо, только при резких движениях курсора, если вести плавно то не работает. Лучше начинает работать, если вместо `mousemove` поставить `mouseover`, но всё равно не идеально: http://jsfiddle.net/z4onhggp/2/

Comment: Решение работает, но пропадает плавность + как вы и сказали, не идеально